# g++: error: /usr/lib/libGL.so: No such file or directory after uninstalling AMD drivers

Tags: linux-mint, drivers, symlink, ati, shared-library

This is a question asked several times all over the internet.

Duplicates:

1. https://askubuntu.com/questions/395544/g-error-or-nosuch-file-or-directory
2. https://askubuntu.com/questions/470532/typelib-usr-lib-libgl-so-1-file-too-short-after-installing-amd-drivers
3. and many more...

The error message is as follows:

```
g++: error: /usr/lib/libGL.so: No such file or directory
```

Now, the issue is that while most people find this error after *installing* the drivers, I have these errors once I *uninstalled* the drivers. I have tried every solution on the web that I can find for this issue, but to no avail.

Also, I have posted this question in [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/490867/g-error-usr-lib-libgl-so-no-such-file-or-directory-after-uninstalling-amd/) and I am using Linux Mint 14.

From [the AskUbuntu forum](https://askubuntu.com/questions/490867/g-error-usr-lib-libgl-so-no-such-file-or-directory-after-uninstalling-amd/) I followed the steps given by Charles to install the open source drivers. But when I do that, I get the following error:

```
/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/libgraph.so.1 is not a symbolic link
```

Comment: I'm confused. You're surpised that `g++` is complaining about a file not existing when you've just removed the package that provides the file?

Comment: Actually, no. I am just getting this error when compiling a file with `g++`.  
What I am concerned about is how do I get back the libGL file? Is it not provided with the open source drivers?